# update_option_{$option} not showing old value

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I have the following bit of code (note, I put the `mail()` function in only to see what the values are):

```
add_action('init','system_init_actions');
function system_init_actions() {
    add_action('update_option_system_number','system_save_number');
}

function system_save_number($oldvalue,$newvalue) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $table_prefix;
    mail('my@email.com','here',print_r($oldvalue,true) . "\n\n" . print_r($newvalue,true));
    $wpdb->update($table_prefix . "system_config",['status'=>'deactivated'],['number'=>$oldvalue]);
    $wpdb->insert($table_prefix . "system_config",['number'=> $newvalue,'created'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'status'=>'pending']);
}
```

In my plugin options page, I have an option named `system_number`. When I save that system number, I get an email (again, only to see the values) which means it is calling the function.

`$newvalue` is passed with no problem, but the function is not receiving `$oldvalue`. I had a look at the `update_option()` method in wp-includes/option.php and it fires `do_action ( "update_option_{$option}", mixed $old_value, mixed $value )`, which should pass the old value.

Why is it not giving me that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pre_update_option_{option_name}` filter.

Example:-

```
function system_save_number( $new_value, $old_value ) {
    mail('my@email.com','here',print_r($old_value ,true) . "\n\n" . print_r($new_value,true));
    return $new_value;
}

function system_init_actions() {
    add_filter( 'pre_update_option_system_number', 'system_save_number', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'system_init_actions' );
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `update_option_{$option}`'s purpose then?

Comment: For this codex documentation is not available [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/update_option_(option_name))